# Capitalize the first letter of each word using a for Loop (can't deal with spacing)

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that is supposed to capitalize  the first letter of each word. I have a neat solution with a `.map`; however, for sake of practice, I'm trying to tackle it using a for loop. Here is what I have achieved:

I have created a for loop, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
function UpperWithCycle(str) {
  str = str.split(' ');
  let result = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += str[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(UpperWithCycle('hello everyone my name is Andrew, how are you doing?'))
```

So, I know I need to add `join(' ')` somewhere here, But I can't seem to figure out where to add it to get the spaces between words. Everywhere I try to add it, I get "join is not a function" 
 So what am I missing here, guys?

Comment: just include a `result += " "` inside the loop after the code you already have, see if it helps

Comment: Make the result as an array and keep pushing the values. Outside the `for loop` join the result array like `result.join(" ")`

Answer (score 2):

You can add space after every word but the last one:

```js
function UpperWithCycle(str) {

  str = str.split(' ');
  let result = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += str[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
    result += i < str.length - 1 ? ' ' : '';
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(UpperWithCycle('hello everyone my name is Andrew, how are you doing?'))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways you can achieve this. You can concatenate " " at the end like this

```
result += str[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str[i].substring(1).toLowerCase() + " ";
```

Or instead of using a *result* variable you simple edit strings in the array like this

```
function UpperWithCycle(str) {
    str = str.split(' ');

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() 
         + str[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return str.join(' ');
 }
 console.log(UpperWithCycle('hello everyone my name is Andrew, how are you doing?'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take each word, uppercase the first letter and then push it back in it's index in the `wordArray` array, the array will have words starting with the uppercased letters.

Then you can join the array using `Array.prototype.join(" ")` to return a string joined with the processed words:

```js
function UpperWithCycle(str) {

   wordArray = str.split(" ");

   for (let i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
       wordArray[i] = wordArray[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + wordArray[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
   }
   return wordArray.join(" ");
 }

 console.log(UpperWithCycle('hello everyone my name is Andrew, how are you doing?'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well all other posted answer works and clearly solves the specified problem, If you want to see one alternate way then you can use replace and regex

```
(^|\s)([a-z])
```

[image]

```js
const changeCase = str => str.replace(/(^|\s)([a-z])/g, (m, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.toUpperCase())

console.log(changeCase('hello everyone my name is Andrew, how are you doing?'))
console.log(changeCase('hello   everyone ?'))
```

Comment: Yes, I have yet to master regular expressions, hopefully, this day will come. I am thanking all the contributors to my question! However, since you brought it up - what do those represent? m, g1, g2

Comment: M is total matched string, G1 and G2 are bacreference to captured groups,